# Can I obtain a source code for RGSS1/RGSS2, assuming it contains LGPL part?

Tags: lgpl

RGSS1/RGSS2 is a game engine for [RPG Maker XP](http://www.rpgmakerweb.com/products/programs/rpg-maker-xp) and RPG Maker VX. The binary of them consist of two files:

- `Game.exe` ... It's about 100KB and seems to be a mere loader.
- `RGSS104J.dll` ... It's about 800KB and seems to contain the actual RGSS code.

RGSS1/RGSS2 consists of three parts:

- The core part of Ruby 1.8.1.
- A special C extension.
- Ruby code embedded on it.

The problem is: **Ruby 1.8.1 contains `regex.c` from GNU and is licensed under LGPL 2.1**. This is mentioned in [the `LEGAL` file in the distribution](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_1/LEGAL).

Although newer Ruby versions contain LGPL-free regex libraries (Oniguruma or Onigmo), a simple experiment (matching `あ` with `/\w/`) suggests that RGSS1/RGSS2 doesn't backport the newer library.

I suspect `regex.c` is linked in `RGSS104J.dll`. Assuming this, is there a chance that I can obtain the source code for `RGSS104J.dll` from the author of RPG Maker (Enterbrain)?

Answer (score 1):

You could surely reach out to them for this if you care really strongly about it.

If they actually statically link with Ruby and its LGPL-licensed code, they would have some redistribution obligations there but these may not be exactly what you think (e.g. you may not receive the source of the game under the LGPL license).

The LGPL [preamble states](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1):

> If you link other code with the library, you must provide complete object files to the recipients, so that they can relink them with the library after making changes to the library and recompiling it.

So you may be entitled to receive a static object library for their own code and the sources of Ruby but not much more.

Nothing really as exciting as you likely expected I guess!